# Any erc20 token transfer simple code in ethers.js?

Tags: erc-20

I tried a lot but the code to transfer erc20 token not working, always return error replacement fee too low 
Unhandledpromiserejectionwarning etc
Any easy code to transfer erc20 token in ethers.js?

Comment: Please show your code, and explain what is not working for you and how you have investigated the problem so far.